# how to include css file required with file loader into index.html using html webpack plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I want to load css without using `style-loader` or `css-loader`. Because it increases the bundle size. So I use `file-loader` to load css file. This generates a css file with random hash as the filename like `2309843904.css`. Now how do I include this in `index.html`.
I use `html-webpack-plugin` but I don't know how to include this css file in `index.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [mini css extract plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) along with style-loader and css-loader as per the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css) will do the same thing.  It will strip the CSS from the bundle into a separate file and load it via an injected link tag in the head of the html.  You can hash the name, for example, like this:

```
      //webpack config module.rules
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        loaders: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          ...
        ],
      },
      //then in module.plugins
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
      chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
    }),
```

Comment: and how do I include the output css file in the index.html?

Comment: mini css injects it.  I don't think you are really saving anything by using file-loader for css instead of css-loader, all loaders do the same thing.  mini css extracts styles into a separate file, injects the <link> tag into the html head, and thus a separate network request is made for the css file.